# Difference between hash_map and unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

I recently discovered that the implementation of the hash map in C++ will be called `unordered_map`.

When I looked up why they weren't just using `hash_map`, I discovered that apparently there are compatibility issues with the implementation of `hash_map` that `unordered_map` resolves (more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_associative_containers_(C%2B%2B))).

That wiki page doesn't give much more information so I wondering if anyone knew some of the issues with `hash_map` that `unordered_map` resolves.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Since there was no hash table defined in the C++ standard library, different implementors of the standard libraries would provide a non-standard hash table often named `hash_map`. Because these implementations were not written following a standard they all had subtle differences in functionality and performance guarantees.

Starting with [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) a hash table implementation has been added to the C++ standard library standard. It was decided to use an alternate name for the class to prevent collisions with these non-standard implementations and to prevent inadvertent use of the new class by developers who had `hash_table` in their code.

The chosen alternate name is `unordered_map` which really is more descriptive as it hints at the class's map interface and the unordered nature of its elements.

Comment: And this is one of the things that show that the `std` namespace didn't quite do what they had hoped.  Not that I know what would have reasonably prevented the problem.

Comment: MSVC had stdext for their Standard extension libraries.

Comment: @MichaelBurr How has `namespace std` failed here? None of the non-standard `hash_map`s are in that namespace (legally, at least), so I don't quite understand that statement by @Stef... Is there a source for that?

Comment: @rubenvb From the [C++ Standards Committee Papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html): "since several vendors have defined classes in namespace std with the hash_* names, defining a standard class with that name would introduce a nasty backward compatibility problem".

Comment: While it makes sense as an more interface-level name it still requires you to have a `std::hash` function for the key type. `unordered_map` gives the illusion that you can just throw in any custom type without needing to do anything else