# What's the scenario difference between hash_map and map in STL?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any principle to choose one over another between hash_map and map in STL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [map vs. hash_map in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189189/map-vs-hash-map-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hash_map` is useful if you are only looking elements by their key. A possible use-case for a `hash_map` would be a dictionary. If the elements need to be in order `map` is the container for that.

And just for clarification (because of the usage of the word "STL"): `hash_map` isn't yet part of the C++ Standard Library, but it has been implemented in several C++ compilers. `unordered_map` was proposed in the C++ Technical Report 1, and it will be defined in the next edition of the standard, [C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x).

Answer (score 1):

hash_map uses a traditional hash_table for its storage and a map uses a red-black tree for it's storage.

Here is a very similar question:

[map vs. hash_map in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189189/map-vs-hash-map-in-c)