# C++ (Hashmap style) Data Structure Ideal For This Scenario?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash

People have asked similar questions about the efficiency of various data structures but none I have read are totally applicable to my scenario so I wondered if people had suggestions for one that was tailored to satisfy the following criteria efficiently:

- Each element will have a **unique** key. There will be **no** possibility of collisions because each element hashes to a different key. **EDIT:** **The key is a 32-bit uint.**
- The elements are all unique and therefore can be thought of as a **set**.
- The only operations required are adding and getting, **not** deletion. These need to be quick as they will be used several 100,000 times in a typical run!
- The order in which elements are kept is **irrelevant**.
- **Speed** is more important than memory-consumption... though it can't be too
  greedy!

I am developing for a company that will use the program commercially so any third-party data structures should come with no copyright protection or anything, but if the STL has a data structure that will do the job efficiently then that would be perfect.

I know there are countless Hashmap/Dictionary style C++ data structures with implementations that are built to satisfy different criteria so if someone can suggest one ideal for this situation then that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

**Edit:**

I found this passage on SO that seems to suggest unordered_map would be good?

> hash_map and unordered_map are generally implemented with hash tables.
>   Thus the order is not maintained. unordered_map insert/delete/query
>   will be O(1) (constant time) where map will be O(log n) where n is the
>   number of items in the data structure. So unordered_map is faster, and
>   if you don't care about the order of the items should be preferred
>   over map. Sometimes you want to maintain order (ordered by the key)
>   and for that map would be the choice.

Comment: and what's the problem with using a normal std::map ?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. I'd just go for hash map. @John std::map uses a red-black tree, and given the description above I think a hash table would be a better fit. How many elements will you be storing (approx)? Will you be adding and getting repeatedly, or will you add your elements and then get them?

Comment: When you say taht the order is irrelevant: do you always access in sequence or by the key? Is there anything you know about the key and how the key is structured?

Comment: @John Paul I was wondering which is most efficient and suitable. Are you suggesting that map is?

Comment: @Mario The Spoon the key is a uint and I retrieve values using keys, and then once at the end of execution I iterate through all entries in the table.

Comment: @Santiago Lezica I will be adding and getting repeatedly during execution and the number of elements will probably be in the 1,000's if not 10's of 1,000's.

Comment: @Santiago, you are right the hashmap seems to be a better fit than the map, as it is faster. Thank you; Greenhouse.. I was just thinking that a map will fit well for your description, but as Santiago suggested, the hashmap should be faster : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189189/map-vs-hash-map-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need definitely sounds like a hash set, C++ has this as either `std::tr1::unordered_set` or in Boost.Unordered.

P.S. Note, however, that TR1 is not **yet** standard, and you'll probably need to get Boost for the implementation.

Comment: If you are using a reasonably new gcc, then you have access to the unordered maps and sets with `g++ -std=c++0x`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Didn't know that, haven't checked the gcc man for a while... Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a prefix tree (with element at each node end) also fits in this scenario. It's damn fast, even faster than hash map because no hash value calculation is done and getting a value is purely O(n) where n is the key length. It's a bit memory hungry but common prefix of keys are shared in the same node path.

EDIT: I assume the keys are string, not simple values like integers

Comment: O(n)? Are you sure? hash map is O(1), binary tree O(logN), so O(n) doesn't seem fast in comparison...

Comment: @juanchopanza but your order of magnitude comment is to do with size of collection as the basis, whereas n here is key length

Answer (score 2):

As for build-in solutions I'd recommand google::dense_hash_map. They are really fast especially for numeric keys. You'll have to decide on a specific key that will be reserved as "empty_key". Moreover here is a really nice [comparison](http://attractivechaos.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/comparison-of-hash-table-libraries/)  of different hash-map implementations.

An excerpt

```
Library         Linux-intCPU (sec)  Linux-strCPU (sec)   Linux PeakMem (MB)
glib            3.490               4.720                24.968
ghthash         3.260               3.460                61.232
CC’s hashtable  3.040               4.050                129.020
TR1             1.750               3.300                28.648
STL hash_set    2.070               3.430                25.764
google-sparse   2.560               6.930                5.42/8.54
google-dense    0.550               2.820                24.7/49.3
khash (C++)     1.100               2.900                6.88/13.1
khash (C)       1.140               2.940                6.91/13.1
STL set (RB)    7.840               18.620               29.388
kbtree (C)      4.260               17.620               4.86/9.59
NP’s splaytree  11.180              27.610               19.024
```

However, when setting a "deleted_key", this map can also perform deletions. So maybe it'll be possible to create a custom solution that is even more efficient. But apart from that minor point, any hash-map should exactly suit your needs (note that "map" is an ordered tree-map and thus slower).

Comment: That was a very interesting read thank you. I am going to look in to google_dense_hash because for int keys it seems to outperform all the others in terms of the author's benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `std::unordered_set` would fit the bill, but without
knowing more about the key, it's difficult to say.  I'm curious about
how you can guarantee that there will be no possibility of collisions:
this implies a small (less than the size of the table), finite set of
keys.  If this is the case, it may be more efficient to map the keys to
a small int, and use `std::vector` (with empty slots for the entries not
present).

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I have updated the question about the key, it is a uint. They are unique because I will look up a hashed value and if it already exists in the table I just use the stored value and not the new one. There is no linear probing or chaining involved because it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Greenhouse Gases If you can create an `std::vector` large enough for all of the possible entries, just using the `uint` directly will be the fastest solution.  If the range of the `uint` isn't restricted, however, you'll have to map `[0...UINT_MAX]` into the size of your table, which means handling collisions.  Any improvement on `std::unordered_set` would have to be based on knowledge of the distribution of the keys in practice.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an `unordered_set`. You can find one in Boost, TR1, or C++0x. If you're hoping to associate the key with a value, then `unordered_map` does just that- also in Boost/TR1/C++0x.