# How do you loop through a std::map?

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, stdmap, range-based-loop

I want to iterate through each element in the `map<string, int>` without knowing any of its string-int values or keys.

What I have so far:

```
void output(map<string, int> table)
{
       map<string, int>::iterator it;
       for (it = table.begin(); it != table.end(); it++)
       {
            //How do I access each element?  
       }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through a c++ map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844886/how-to-loop-through-a-c-map)

Comment: you most probably don't want the function to get the map by value, would be better to get it as `const map<string, int>& table`

Answer (score 980, accepted):

You can achieve this like following :

```
map<string, int>::iterator it;

for (it = symbolTable.begin(); it != symbolTable.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first    // string (key)
              << ':'
              << it->second   // string's value 
              << std::endl;
}
```

---

With *C++11* <sub>( and onwards )</sub>,

```
for (auto const& x : symbolTable)
{
    std::cout << x.first  // string (key)
              << ':' 
              << x.second // string's value 
              << std::endl;
}
```

---

With *C++17* <sub>( and onwards )</sub>,

```
for (auto const& [key, val] : symbolTable)
{
    std::cout << key        // string (key)
              << ':'  
              << val        // string's value
              << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: add the "auto" type in front of "it"

Comment: @P0W Why "auto const&" for C++11 but "const auto&" for C++17? Any difference between "auto const&" and "const auto&"?

Comment: There is no difference, it's just a matter of taste. However it seems like @P0W 's taste is not very conistent...

Comment: Thanks for updating with the C++17 one, I was looking for the `auto const& [key, val] : symbolTable` format!

Comment: @P0W C++ 17 example is not working in VS2017, what is the problem?

Comment: @haram the feature might not be implemented yet in the version of visual studio 2017 compiler you're using.

Comment: then how can I test that feature? gcc?

Comment: @haram You might have to set "ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)" in the project settings (Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Language > C++ Language Standard)

Comment: doesn't have to be "auto const&" BTW; can be "auto&" if you wish to mutate

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), a forwarding reference is the safest way to use range for loops:
`for (auto&& x: f())`

Comment: @Eric • just remember the rule `const` always binds to the thing to its immediate left, unless it is first in which case it binds to the thing to its immediate right.  (If you always do it the first way, you won't have to think about the exception.  If you always do it the special case latter way when possible, then you have to think hard when you see the general way.)

Comment: One could also use `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: 'Structured bindings' is what MSVC refers to the C++17 language feature as.

Comment: @Eric, `const` always refers to its left. if there's nothing there, then refers to its right.

Comment: Any reason why "auto const&" is used? As it's fine with just "auto".

Comment: It's better to use pre-increment for your iterators.

Comment: I have noticed that ASAN sanitizer has an issue with the first solution. When I debugged the code I noticed that incrementing the iterator, strangely, made it point to a different place rather than the map.end().
I have used asan_clang as my compiler.
Can someone tell me how is it possible?

Comment: Well to answer my own issue, it was the problem of postfix and prefix. Please use ++it instead of it++.

Answer (score 39):

Try the following

```
for ( const auto &p : table )
{
   std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

The same can be written using an ordinary for loop

```
for ( auto it = table.begin(); it != table.end(); ++it  )
{
   std::cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Take into account that value_type for `std::map` is defined the following way

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type
```

Thus in my example p is a const reference to the value_type where Key is `std::string` and T is `int`

Also it would be better if the function would be declared as

```
void output( const map<string, int> &table );
```

Answer (score 14):

The `value_type` of a `map` is a `pair` containing the key and value as it's `first` and `second` member, respectively.

```
map<string, int>::iterator it;
for (it = symbolTable.begin(); it != symbolTable.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << '\n';
}
```

Or with C++11, using range-based for:

```
for (auto const& p : symbolTable)
{
    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As @Vlad from Moscow says,
Take into account that `value_type` for `std::map` is defined the following way:

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type
```

This then means that if you wish to replace the keyword `auto` with a more explicit type specifier, then you could this;

```
for ( const pair<const string, int> &p : table ) {
   std::cout << p.first << '\t' << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Just for understanding what `auto` will translate to in this case.

Answer (score 12):

As P0W has provided complete syntax for each C++ version, I would like to add couple of more points by looking at your code

- Always take `const &` as argument as to avoid extra copies of the same object.
- use `unordered_map` as its always faster to use. See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799593/how-to-choose-between-map-and-unordered-map)

here is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

void output(const auto& table)
{
   for (auto const & [k, v] : table)
   {
        std::cout << "Key: " << k << " Value: " << v << std::endl;
   }
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<string, int> mydata = {
        {"one", 1},
        {"two", 2},
        {"three", 3}
    };
    output(mydata);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain, how multiple copies of same object can get created if we don't use const& ? Is there any edge condition when it can happen?

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari its the reference of the variable `&` which avoids creating the multiple copies and when we take the reference, we do not want it to be modified hence we use `const`

Answer (score 3):

it can even be done with a classic `for` loop.
advancing the iterator manually.

```
typedef std::map<int, int> Map;

Map mymap;

mymap['a']=50;
mymap['b']=100;
mymap['c']=150;
mymap['d']=200;

bool itexist = false;
int sizeMap = static_cast<int>(mymap.size());
auto it = mymap.begin();
for(int i = 0; i < sizeMap; i++){
    std::cout << "Key: " << it->first << " Value: " << it->second << std::endl;
    it++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you just want to iterate over the content without changing values
do:

```
for(const auto & variable_name : container_name(//here it is map name)){
    cout << variable_name.first << " : " << variable_name.second << endl; 
}
```

If you want to modify the contents of the map, remove the `const` and keep `&` (if you want to modify directly the contents inside container). If you want to work with a *copy* of the container values, remove the `&` sign too; after that, you can access them by using `.first` and `.second` on "variable_name".

Answer (score 1):

Other way :

```
map <int, string> myMap = {
    { 1,"Hello" },
    { 2,"stackOverflow" }
};
for (auto iter = cbegin(myMap); iter != cend(myMap); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->second << endl;
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.