# Class destructor to delete other class

Tags: c++, class, destructor

I need help creating a class destructor. I don't really understand how to create one but I do understand what they do. 
Since new is called to create users and prizes, I need to write a destructor that calls delete on all the users and prizes.

```
class User {
  public:
    string username;
    string realname;
    int points;
    set <string> phone_numbers;
};
class Prize { 
  public:
   string id;
   string description;
   int points;
   int quantity;
};

class CodeProcessor {
    ~CodeProcessor(); //destructor 
  protected:
    map <string, User *> Names;
    map <string, Prize *> Prizes;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the maps contain objects, rather than pointers ?

Comment: *The destructor doesn't have to clear the maps or sets* -- You have no control over that.  The destructor of the `map` will be called automatically anyway when `~CodeProcessor()` is invoked, thus clearing the map.

Comment: Also, consider what happens if you copy or assign `CodeProcessor` objects.  Your destructor will invoke undefined behavior, since `CodeProcessor` has incorrect copy semantics.  Time to read up on [the rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie some backstory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568410/inserting-into-a-map . The asker is stuck with crippled code because of a poorly written header they've been tasked with implementing.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't want to seem needy, but I need help with a Delete_User function, but I can't ask another question. If I updated the question would help out?

Comment: @user9573040 Please don't tell us that `User`'s destructor is also borked and you need to destroy it from the outside...

Comment: @user9573040 Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the destructor like this

```
CodeProcessor::~CodeProcessor()
{
    for (auto n : Names)
    {
        delete n.second;
    }
    for (auto p : Prizes)
    {
        delete p.second;
    }
}
```

But then again, why don't you just make the maps contain objects, rather than pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the values in the map and delete each one. In C++17 you can use the following

```
for (auto [key, user] : Names) {
    delete user;
}
for (auto [key, prize] : Prizes) {
    delete prize;
}
```

More information on looping over maps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map)