# what does `auto const& x ` do in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator, auto

I'm reading the accepted answer to this question [C++ Loop through Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281979/c-loop-through-map)

An example in that answer:

```
for (auto const& x : symbolTable)
{
  std::cout << x.first  // string (key)
            << ':' 
            << x.second // string's value 
            << std::endl ;
}
```

What does `auto const&` mean in this case?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is a poor replacement for a [good C++ language reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). All of the concepts in the question will be covered in detail early on in any good text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This uses a [range-based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) statement.  It declares a variable named `x`, which is a reference-to-const of the value type of the container.  Since `symbolTable` is a `std::map<string, int>`, the compiler assigns to `x` a const reference to the map's `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const std::string, int>`.

This is equivalent to `std::pair<const std::string, int> const &x`, but shorter. And it will adapt `auto`matically whenever the type of the sequence is changed.

Comment: You have a pretty good explanation for what the loop is doing, but you are not explaining what `auto` is doing. You should add that