# When I loop through a C++ map, why does it give me an instantiation error?

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, c++14

I am trying to loop through a map but nothing I try seems to work... I declare and define the map as follows:

```cpp
// loop through the strings and group based on length
map<size_t, NGroup> groups;
for (size_t i = 0; i < strs.size(); i++) {
    size_t len = strs[i].size();
    if (groups.count(len) != 0) {
        groups.at(len).appendString(strs[i]);
    } else {
        NGroup g(strs[i]);
        groups[len] = g;
    }
}
```

with the following relevant classes:

```cpp
class AnagramGroup {
public:
    map<char, size_t> freqs;
    map<char, size_t> ground;
    vector<string> anagrams;

    AnagramGroup(map<char, size_t> m, string anagram) {
        freqs = m;
        ground = m;
        anagrams.push_back(anagram);
    }
    AnagramGroup(AnagramGroup &other);
};

class NGroup {
public:
    vector<string> strings;
    vector<AnagramGroup> groups;

    NGroup(string str) {
        vector<string> strs = {str};
        strings = strs;
    }
    NGroup(vector<string> strs) {
        strings = strs;
    }
    NGroup(NGroup &other);

    void appendString(string str) {
        strings.push_back(str);
    }
};
```

And I have tried to loop through the map using the ways listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26282015/10084882):

```cpp
map<size_t, NGroup>::iterator it;
for (it = groups.begin(); it != groups.end(); it++) {
...
}
```

```cpp
for (const auto &p : groups) {
...
}
```

But I always get the same error:

```
In file included from prog_joined.cpp:1:
In file included from ./precompiled/headers.h:13:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/cmath:1927:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/specfun.h:45:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: error: the parameter for this explicitly-defaulted copy constructor is const, but a member or base requires it to be non-const
      constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                ^
Line 61: Char 38: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::pair<const unsigned long, NGroup>' requested here
        for (it = groups.begin(); it != groups.end(); it++) {
                                     ^
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Aside: `strs[i]` either isn't doing what you think it is, or you should be using a `std::vector<NGroup>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::map needs to support this semantic:

```
NGroup ng& = groups["some key that doesn't exist in this map"];
```

When the key is not in the map, it default constructs an instance of your value type of the map and assigns it at that key. Without a default constructor, it doesn't know what to pass to you object's constructor.

Thus, NGroup needs a default constructor. This fixed it for me:

```
class NGroup {
public:
    vector<string> strings;
    vector<AnagramGroup> groups;

    NGroup() {  // add this

    }
```

Also, neither NGroup nor AnagramGroup need a copy constructor since the default constructor will do the right thing. So you can just remove both.  The copy constructor is only needed when a member variable can't be trivially copied or rely or the member variable's own copy constructors.

Now let's clean up the rest of your code by passing most parameters as const reference so you aren't making so me inadvertent copies of those strings and collections.

```
class AnagramGroup {
public:
    map<char, size_t> freqs;
    map<char, size_t> ground;
    vector<string> anagrams;

    AnagramGroup(const map<char, size_t>& m, const string& anagram) :
        freqs(m), ground(m), anagrams({anagram}) {
    }

};

class NGroup {
public:
    vector<string> strings;
    vector<AnagramGroup> groups;

    NGroup() {

    }

    NGroup(const string& str) : strings({ str }) {
    }

    NGroup(const vector<string>& strs) : strings(strs) {
    }

    void appendString(const string& str) {
        strings.push_back(str);
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! Adding the default constructor alone didn't work but also using const reference parameters fixed it up! Why exactly are you passing most parameters as const reference? I thought that C++ containers handled copying. Does your implementation copy only the reference (pointer) to the container? (Sorry in advance! I come from a C background so some of the memory things that are hidden away from me are a bit confusing)

Comment: @joshua Initializing an object using a reference parameter copies the referenced object.  So, for example, `NGroup(const vector<string>& strs) : strings(strs) {}` copies the object referenced by `strs` into the object's `strings` member.  Accepting a parameter by reference-to-const prevents it from being unnecessarily copied a second time (from the original object to the function parameter).

Comment: Gotcha that makes sense, thanks! If I wanted to prevent any copies and move the object referenced by `strs` into the object's `strings` member, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Prefer to `= default` a constructor instead of empty-bodying it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your "copy constructors" aren't really a copy constructors since they accept their parameters by reference to non-const.  Change your copy constructors to accept a reference-to-const or remove them if all they do is a field-by-field copy, since the compiler will auto-generate copy constructors that do that.

The elements of a `std::map` are `std::pair`s, and `std::pair` is copyable.  When instantiating the copy constructor of `std::pair<const size_t, NGroup>`, the compiler is going to come up with something like this:

```
pair(const pair& other)
    : first(other.first),
      second(other.second)
{}
```

But since `other` is a reference-to-const, that means that `other.second` is a `const NGroup`.  `NGroup` has no constructor that accepts a `const NGroup` as a parameter, and so the `std::pair` instantiation is invalid.

Comment: @selbie is saying that I don't need a copy constructor...

Comment: You need one, but you don't need to explicitly define one.  Like I said, if your copy constructor doesn't do anything but a field-by-field copy then the compiler's default-generated one will do exactly the same thing and so you can leave your definition of it out.

Comment: Ah okay! I had previously gotten an error that said `Line 19: Char 5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument 'strs', but no arguments were provided
Line 12: Char 7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
Line 12: Char 7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided` so I thought the solution was to add a copy constructor. But I see now that `no arguments were provided` indicating that I was missing the default constructor.