# c++ equivalent to $obj->{$var}

Tags: c++, object

I'm looking for a C++ equivalent for the following PHP code

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->test = "aaaa";
$var = "test";
echo $obj->{$var};
```

Is even possible in C? I keep looking for hours and no luck.

Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a hash table.

Comment: Yes.  Try std::map<T>

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @JCx: Or `std::unordered_map`

Comment: @Keith probably a better choice, agreed.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent - you can't get a member name as a string and convert it to the address of a member variable/function unless you have the offset of every single member variable/function. You have the same problem with VBScript, Javascript and Snobol.  The features of some languages are just not translatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, string> obj;
    obj["test"] = "aaaa";
    string var = "test";
    cout << obj[var] << endl;
}
```

It's not quite the same, as test is a string in both cases here.  If it's the difference between **"test"** and plain **test** that's important then the answer becomes a bit more complicated.

See also: [How to choose between map and unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799593/how-to-choose-between-map-and-unordered-map) to explain the discussion in the comments.