# What is difference between map and unordered map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

According to: [This Tutorial](http://thispointer.com/unordered_map-usage-tutorial-and-example/)

I can't understand the difference between `std::map` and `std::unorderedmap`. When and Why we should use **Map** and **Unorderedmap**?

Comment: This answer displays differences in a table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13799886/5601284

Comment: Beyond the obvious that [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is *ordered* (sorted on key) while [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is not?

Comment: In the same link you posted is another post `http://thispointer.com/map-vs-unordered_map-when-to-choose-one-over-another/`

Comment: The difference is in internal representation and the speed of elements insertion and lookup. Map is associative container of sorted key-value pairs implemented as binary trees. Unordered map is implemented via a hash function and an array of buckets with linked lists.

Answer (score 1):

As I've read in tutorial you provided, search speed in `std::unorderedmap` is `O(1)`. While in `std::map` it's `O(log2(n))`, where `n` is size of the map. 
So if you have to call `std::find` often, you can consider this option. While choosing hash function isn't an easy task.

Comment: "search speed in std::unorderedmap is O(1)" this is not quite true.

Comment: @Slava Well, I didn't use  `std::unorderedmap`, but tutorial states that hash of the key is calculated and then compared. Is this more to logarithmic complexity then to  `O(1)` ?

Comment: It is not that, you compare O(log2(n)) in `std::map` vs O(1) in `std::unordered_map` but you cannot compare them, as that not apple to apple comparison. `std::map` guarantees O(log2(n)) while `std::unordered_map` usually have O(1), but can degrade to O(n). Your statement says that search speed is always O(1), which is not quite correct and can be misleading.