# How can i use multidimensional arrays to store multiple elements, then retrieve elements

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to create a small car park management system. What I want to do is to have users input their vehicle number and it will store it into an array. I also want other elements like check in time, a serial number, vehicle type, etc. to be stored with the vehicle number.

I want to know how I can use a multidimensional array to store all what I mentioned into the vehicle number so that when the user types their veh number again, it would show all other elements stored within that.

Sorry if I'm not making it clear enough.

Comment: Why not make a `class Vehicle` and then have a `std::vector<Vehicle>`? Then you class can have data members like time, serial number, etc.

Comment: @CoryKramer I thought the same. Or if you don't want to create a class you can just use `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string>> vehicle_data;`.

Answer (score 5):

The first step is to use a struct to organize your data, e.g.:

```
struct Vehicle {
    int id;
    int serial;
    VehicleType type;
};
```

The second question is what is the approprate container for your objects. An array is fine in general as you can easily append to it. That would then be

```
std::vector<Vehicle> vehicles;
```

However whenever you want to lookup a vehicle by its id, you will need to go through all of them to find the matching one.
More efficient would be a map. There are several variants but for starters, a regular one will be fine:

```
std::map<int, Vehicle> vehicles;
```

Example insertion:

```
// given int vin, int serial
vehicles[vin] = {vin, serial, VehicleType::Car}
```

An alternative would be the `std::unordered_map`.

You need to familiarize yourself with these containers so you can learn about their proper use and advantages/disadvantages. A good starter is here: [How to choose between map and unordered_map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799593/how-to-choose-between-map-and-unordered-map)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're looking for something like a map: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/ where the key is your vehicle number and the mapped value is the vehicle's details (whatever you'd like to add there).

Edit: As an example in your case

`std::map<int, vehicle> vehicleMap;`

To use that `vehicleMap` properly you should

1. define a `struct` or `class` of type `vehicle`
2. create the objects of type `vehicle` you want to use
3. add your desired details to the `vehicle` objects
4. insert the `vehicle` objects to the map with `vehicleMap.insert(int, vehicle)`.

then you can use `vehicleMap.find(<int>);` to retrieve all the details of your vehicle. : )

Comment: You can actually give a quick little example to use maps in this case if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, edited to add an example.

Comment: Hey @johnnydead83, your example is great unitl the insert statement. You probably mean `vehicleMap.insert({id, vehicle})` or similar - as otherwise the key is missing.

Comment: Thanks, @ypnos I did indeed miss that. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use maps for this purpose as such:

```
std::map<int, Vehicle> vehicle_data;
```

..and here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    std::string name;

    Vehicle(std::string _name) : name(_name) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, Vehicle> vehicle_data;

    vehicle_data.insert({ 1, Vehicle("vehicle name 1")});
    vehicle_data.insert({ 3, Vehicle("vehicle name 3") });
    vehicle_data.insert({ 2, Vehicle("vehicle name 2") });

    auto it1 = vehicle_data.find({ 1 });
    auto it2 = vehicle_data.find({ 2 });
    auto it3 = vehicle_data.find({ 4 });

    if (it1 != vehicle_data.end()) std::cout << it1->second.name << std::endl;
    if (it2 != vehicle_data.end()) std::cout << it2->second.name << std::endl;
    if (it3 != vehicle_data.end()) std::cout << it3->second.name << std::endl;
}
```

In the above code, I've inserted 3 vehicles into `vehicle_data` and then I've used `find()` to get the iterator pointing to the element with int value of `1`, `2`, and `4` and then printed the second element's (Vehicle's) name.

Comment: better do not use `find` wihtout checking if it retunred `end()`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yep that makes sense. I've edited the answer.

Comment: it will not "cause errors". Dereferencing the end iterator is plain undefined behavior. In the second code you need not look up the elements twice, you can use the iterators you already found

Comment: That's what I meant by errors. But I've edited the answer.

Comment: ub is not "errors", in some sense its the opposite, because typically compilers to not diagnose it

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Alright. I actually was saying that in the sense of compiler errors and exceptions. But thanks for informing me.

Comment: better remove the code with UB altogether. Ppl tend to copy past code without understanding what it does, and your first code can do anything